# How are global objects handled in threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, orm, global-variables, pyramid

I would like to create a Pyramid app with an orm which I am writing (currently in deep alpha status). I want to plug the orm into the app sanely and thus I want to know how global objects are handled in multithreading.

In the file:
https://www.megiforge.pl/p/elephantoplasty/source/tree/0.0.1/src/eplasty/ctx.py
you can see, there is a global object called ctx which contains a default session. What if I run set_context() and start_session() in middleware at ingress? Can I expect then to have a separate session in ctx in every thread? Or is there a risk that two threads will use the same session?

Comment: For the posterity of this question it'd be nice if you could paste the code into your question instead of linking to your "master" branch which is very likely to change by the time someone comes by to read it.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel - you are right - it wasn't a good idea. But I still think the full gives better view. So I edit my post and link to tag instead of master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are shared between all threads, so if you run those functions the threads will conflict with each other in unpredictable ways.

To do what you want you can use thread local data, using [threading.local](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local). You need to remove the global definition of `ctx` and then create the following function.

```
def get_ctx():
    thread_data = threading.local()
    if not hasattr(thread_data, "ctx"):
         thread_data.ctx = Ctx()
    return thread_data.ctx
```

Then, everywhere you reference `ctx` call `get_ctx()` instead. This will ensure that your context is not shared between threads.

Comment: Your approach doesn't work. Every call to get_ctx() returns a new object. But you pointed me a good way. What I did was deriving my Ctx class from threading.local. This way it works as intended. So I accept your reply as a good point.